# How to delete all messages of a particular user using sendbird javascript api in 1-1 chat.

Tags: javascript, sendbird

i am using send bird java script api in chat application. as i went through doc of send bird java script it is having way to delete a particular message of current user in 1-1 chat.by using 
currentUserChannel.deleteMessage(message, function(response, error){

```
    });
```

but what if i want to delete all messages of a particular user in 1 to 1 chat.i am not getting any method to delete all message of a particular user . please suggest me how can i do it ..??and thanks for your suggestion in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think it’s directly possible using the JavaScript SDK, but one solution would be to use the [Platform API](https://docs.sendbird.com/platform). To outline the steps,

1. Retrieve a list of all the user's channels using the [List my Group Channels](https://docs.sendbird.com/platform#user_3_list_my_group_channels) request, and store each channel's URL in a list.
2. For each channel, fetch all of the user’s messages using the [List messages request](https://docs.sendbird.com/platform#messages_3_list_messages) with `?sender_id=<target_user_id>`, and store each message’s ID in a list.
3. Then, delete each message with the [Delete a message request](https://docs.sendbird.com/platform#messages_3_delete_a_message), passing the message ID as the parameter.

Effectively, you would have two loops:

```
for(channel):
    for(user's message in channel):
        delete message
```